# how to send facebook message automatically without api

Tags: facebook, message

guys

now i knew how to send message without using facebook api,
i could use url to fill the message textarea in facebook's website

www.facebook.com/messages/[user_id]?msg_prefill=XXX

but here i'd like to know how to send this message automatically

in April, i found a way to click "send" button automatically (find "send" button in html text and click it),

but now facebook hide theses html text so that i can't find this button in html text.
Therefore, can anybody provide some ways or point to send message automatically.

thanks

Comment: i have found out reason why can't i find out "send" button.

the button's id was changed.

however i still can't find out this button's id(because this button doesn't have name)

so i only change my code to find out this id.

Answer (score 0):

Use the console in you browser (usually F12 to open) firefox console is the most powerfull, your console should have a command like "element inspection" or similar, use this tool to analize the button you want, read ing the code you should find someting like "on click" or simsimilar, after this you will find a java command to push the button. Anyway to do this kind of stuff without being a programmer,use selenium IDE, very easy,only for firefox,you must download it from firefox as add on. Good luck!